# Why does loading Test::More eliminate my bug?

Tags: regex, perl, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a test for [this bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=81061).  I've already found a solution to the bug; what I can't understand is why my tests didn't catch the bug before release.

The problem boils down to this command line printing `Ver: 0` when it's supposed to print `Ver: 1.00`:

```
perl -Mversion -e 'printf "Ver: %s\n", ("v1.00" =~ /v(.+)/ ? version->parse($1) : "no");'
```

However, if you insert `-MTest::More` before `-Mversion`, then it prints `Ver: 1.00`.

So my question is why does loading [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::More) change the behavior of my code?  (For bonus points, why does using `"$1"` instead of `$1` eliminate the bug?)

I'm using Perl 5.14.2, Test::More 0.98, and version 0.88.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug in version. `$1` is magical var, and version fails to process magic before checking if the arg is defined. It thinks `$1` is undefined if no one ever read from `$1`. If someone has read from `$1` (e.g. Test::More), then it appears defined to version.

```
$ perl -Mversion -E'
    "v1.00" =~ /v(.+)/ or die;
    $x=$1 if $ARGV[0];
    say version->parse($1);
' 0
0

$ perl -Mversion -E'
    "v1.00" =~ /v(.+)/ or die;
    $x=$1 if $ARGV[0];
    say version->parse($1);
' 1
1.00
```

I have filed a bug report: [Perl RT#115660](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=115660)

Comment: ok, so it took me a while to determine that. Damn you, Leon! ;)

Comment: Leon was faster, but I like your answer better (+ bug report), so I'm accepting yours.

Answer (score 8):

```
perl -Mversion -E 'sub TIESCALAR { bless {} }; sub FETCH { die "HERE" }; tie $foo, __PACKAGE__; say version->new($foo)'
```

version is buggy, it doesn't call get magic properly, thus never populating $1. If it works when loading Test::More first, that's only because there's still an old value in $1